# How can I export a picture with white background in Inventor VBA?

Tags: vba, image, export, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

My set-up on my desktop pc is all... dark. Not that I'm a goth or something but it is pleasing for the eyes. However, whenever I save a picture in Inventor I have to change the background setting to white. Then change it back to dark-mode after I finished the image export.

I once had a VBA-code to easily save a picture while backdrop is set to white. All with one button. Can someone help me? I know the code isn't that difficult.

The code should work as follows:

- As user, set the desired angle and distance in the main viewer.
- Push a button and a VBA script runs in the background.
- A export image saved on desktop with a predefined name. But the background is set to white.

Thank you!

Searched for VBA-codes online. Searched in my own folders for the code I once used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily you can export active view with transparent or explicitly white background without modifying  application settings

```vb
Sub ExportActiveView()
    Dim v As View
    Set v = ThisApplication.ActiveView
    
    Dim width, height As Integer
    width = 300
    height = 300
    
    'Export with transparent background
    Dim options As NameValueMap
    Set options = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap
    options.value("TransparentBackground") = True
    Call v.SaveAsBitmapWithOptions("C:\Temp\img.png", width, height, options)
    
    'Export with white bacground
    Dim white As Color
    Set white = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateColor(255, 255, 255)
    Call v.Camera.SaveAsBitmap("C:\Temp\img.jpg", width, height, white)
End Sub
```